# Appending map to another map using GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis, vector, append

I'm trying to simply append a map to other map, without any sort of geometric operations as merge or intersects, just the original geometries with theirs attributes. 
This is what I already tried:

```
# input maps are poly2 and poly3
# First, i change the categories of poly3 to avoid categories conflicts:
# see http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.patch.html 
v.category in=poly3 option=sum cat=10000 out=poly3_category --overwrite
g.remove vect=poly3
g.rename vect=poly3_category,poly3
# I update the cat column of the table as well (why this is not done 
# automatically by v.category??)
v.db.update poly3 col=cat qcol="cat+10000" 

# now the to maps are patched together
db.droptable -f table=polygons    
v.patch -e input=poly2,poly3 output=polygons --overwrite

# export to result as geojson:
v.out.ogr in=polygons olayer=polygons format=GeoJSON dsn=/tmp/polygons.json type=area
```

The geometries of the result map polygons.json look good, but the attributes are messy: I can not distinguish which records come from poly2 and which ones from poly3. Many records have only empty attributes. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please, accept the answer or create a new answer with the solution you've used and accept that answer. (So, this question is marked as solved.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, the question was answered in the GRASS User list:

http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2014-December/071451.html